# Jquery clientscript not responding in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I works on local but does not work on live server

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('users', "
    var user_id = $('#uId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'user/personalInfo'
        ,type:'get'
        ,dataType:'json'
        ,data:{id:user_id}
        ,success:function(data){
            //append to popup window
        }
    });
```

");

Comment: post the error which you face in server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try by this way**

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('users', "
    var use_id = $('#uId').val();
    var url = window.location.href.split('/');
    var base_url = url[0] + '//' + url[2] + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url:base_url + 'user/personalInfo'
        ,type:'get'
        ,dataType:'json'
        ,data:{id:user_id}
        ,success:function(data){
            //append to popup window
        }
    });
");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Yii::app()->createUrl('user/personalInfo')` fro creating the url

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('users', "
    var user_id = $('#uId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'" . Yii::app()->createUrl('user/personalInfo') . "'
        ,type:'get'
        ,dataType:'json'
        ,data:{id:user_id}
        ,success:function(data){
            //append to popup window
        }
    });
```